# Carbon('last day of October')->modify('+1 month') unexpected result

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

Can anyone explain to me, why `(new Carbon('last day of October'))->modify('+1 month');` returns

```
 Carbon {#326
    +"date": "2016-12-01 00:00:00.000000"
    +"timezone_type": 3
    +"timezone": "Europe/"
  }
```

Same with `modify('-1 month')`. Could that be that when modifying by a month, Carbon substracts or adds a number of days in the target month? So, when we add "1 month" to the last day of October, Carbon adds 31 days to October 31 and return December 1st...

Comment: Try `->addMonth(1)` or `->subMonth(1)`.

Comment: I can't, since both `'last day of October'` and `'+1 month'` is generated elsewhere and could be `'+12 days'`, `'-4 years'` with `'first day of this month'` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `last day of October` evaluates to `Oct 31st` of the current year.

`Oct 31st +1 month` is *Nov* 31st. That's an invalid date. But obviously it should be the same as `Nov 30th +1 day`, which is `Dec 1st`.

The problem is that both evaluations are done independently. `modify("+1 month")` doesn't know that it's supposed to result in the "last day" of that month.

You can't get around this issue by using `endOfMonth()`, except when it's actually the last date change in the chain. It's basically identical to `modify("last day of this month")` but also advances the time to 1µs before midnight.

Instead you could concatenate the strings into a single expression, eg. `last day of October +1 month`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems Carbon library still has some bugs.
You can try this way.

```
Carbon::create()->endOfMonth()->month(10)->modify('+1 month')
```

You can check the result at http://phpio.net/tools/carbon

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I used the `sub` and `addMonth` with `NoOverflow`:

```
//September 30th        
$previousDate = Carbon::now()->subMonthNoOverflow();
//October 31st
$currentDate = Carbon::now();
//November 30th
$nextMonth = Carbon::now()->addMonthNoOverflow();
```

Comment: In my case I have to use `modify()` as the modifier string is generated elsewhere and completely arbitrary.